# Wildfly Deployment through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, wildfly, continuous-deployment

I have spent many hours trying to find a solution for this one.

I need to deploy from Jenkins to a remote Wildfly (no Docker, Vagrant etc) and I want the person who deploys to be able to choose the version to be deployed. The version's war should be retrieved from a repository (Artifactory) or int he worse case, checkout from svn tag and build

Anyone has a working example?

Comment: Cargo can remote deploy as a maven task.

Comment: Do you have a working sample for wildfly? i couldn't find any

Comment: No. I just adapted the examples on the cargo website.

Comment: An example will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin and http://cargo.codehaus.org/WildFly+8.x

Comment: There are no examples on these links. I ask for a working example because I was not able to make it work when I tried it last week.

Comment: Show what doesn't work.

Comment: As you can see from my answer I went with cli deployment. It works and it is easier than cargo configuration

Comment: Great you made it work.

Answer (score 2):

How would you define the version that needs to be deployed in Jenkins ?

http://blog.arungupta.me/2014/11/deployment-pipeline-javaee7-wildfly-arquillian-openshift-jenkins-techtip56/ shows how to deploy to remote WildFly using Jenkins on OpenShift. The app is deployed if the tests pass, and not otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your time! 
I am not sure how you would define the version. Maybe using a parametrised build? But even so, how would you deploy the war? If the artifact is a war produced using the release plugin (this is the 'usual' way to release with maven, isn't?) how can I reference it? Can it be referenced by the job that produced the release? I am really lost. Is my requirement unrealistic? How does everyone deploys specific releases?

Comment: Jenkins Workflow plugin allows you to define those parameters. Take a look at http://jenkins-ci.org/content/workflow-plugin-10

Comment: I will take a look at it but how would it solve the deployment part?

Comment: thank you for all your time I really appreciate it! I did not see something in your post about deploying a specific release, you deploy the 'current' version of your project, did I miss something? My requirement was to deploys specific version from Jenkins (so a non-developer can do it). Check my answer for what I finally did. I look forward for your comments if something seems wrong or sub-optimal

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else needs this, my solution is the following (although maybe not optimal):

1) Create free-style job in Jenkins. Check 'This build is parameterised' and add a string parameter (e.g. VERSION)  which will be defined by the user when he runs the job.

2) Add a build step 'Artifact resolver' (Repository Connector Plugin) and define the artifact that you want to deploy. This should resolve the dependency using the Artifactory Repository where your war is released. 
On the 'version' field add the version parameter e.g. ${VERSION}. 
On the 'target file name' field add a name for your war e.g. test.war

3) Add another build step 'Execute Windows batch command'. 
ATTENTION: You need to have the jboss-cli in your Jenkins machine as an environmental variable.

The script to execute should be of the form:

jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=ip:adminPort --user=admin --password=*** --commands="deploy test.war --force"

This works for me even though if anyone has a more optimal solution I would like to hear about it. For example it would be much more interesting if the user could choose from a select box the version to be deployed instead of having to write the correct version (no validation)